# How to put two different shortcodes with the custom HTML widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode

My problem is very simple but i can't find a solution. I have a piece of code in a Custom HTML Widget. That piece of code show me one contact form 7. 
Until this moment is only necessary one language but now i need two languages. So, i duplicate the contact form 7 and i put one with message in english and the other in Portuguese but i can't show the shortcodes when i try put some javascript.
There is any way?

[image]

```
<script>
var portuguese = '[contact-form-7 id="156" title="Portugues"]';
var english = '[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact form 1"]';
var url = 'pt';

if(url === 'pt') {
return portuguese;
} else {
return english;
}
</script>
```

If I put just [contact-form-7 id="156" title="Portugues"] works fine but i need create a condition.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem.
Like i said the problem was easy but i lost a lot of time indeed.

So i just joked with the DOM. Is not the best solution but works.

```
[contact-form-7 id="156" title="Portugues" class="teste2"]
[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact form 1" class="teste"]

<script>

var url = window.location.href;
var urlSplit = url.split('/');

    console.log(urlSplit.length);
    if(urlSplit.length >= 6) {
document.getElementById('wpcf7-f7-o2').style.display = "none";
        alert('pt');
} else {
document.getElementById('wpcf7-f156-o1').style.display = "none";
}


</script>
```